# html using css. wont format the way i want

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the header main and footer to have 855px with the float left to with 570px and the right side to float with 255px. it wont line up correctly without going into the other section.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>BrightIdeas</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="  C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\html\css\style.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\html\css\reset.css"/>
            <link rel="javascript" href="C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\html\css\js\app.js">
    </head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper"> 
        <div id="header">
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>BrightIdeas</h1>

                    <nav><a href="signUp.html">Sign Up!</a> | <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a> | <a href="#">Support</a>
                    </nav>                         

                </div>
            </header>
        </div>  

<div id="content">
    <main>
        <div class="container">

            <div  id="left">
                    <h2>BrightIdeas will change your life!</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                    <h3>Here's why you need bright ideas</h3>
                    <ul><li>It fits your lifestyle</li>
                    <li>It's awesome</li>
                    <li>We say so</li></ul>
            </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <img src="C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\html\brightIdeas\images\brightidea.png" alt="an image of a lightbulb"/>
                </div>          
            </div>
    </main>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <footer>
            <div id="contact">
                <h5>Contact Us</h5>
                <p>BrightIdeas</p>
                <p>666 Sixth Street</p>
                <p>Amherst, NY 12345</p>
            </div>


            <div id="sitemap">
                <h5>Sitemap</h5>
                <ul><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li></ul>
            </div>
    </footer>
</div>

</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

here is my stylesheet. ive changed it multiple times so it is a little jumbled
    #body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin bottom: 120px;
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
     }

```
#main{
    min-width:855px;
    overflow: auto;

}
#header {
     background: white;
     min-width:855;
     overflow:auto;
     height: 70px;
     padding:20px 20px;

 }
div img{
    float:right;

}
div h1{
    float:left;
    width:570px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 250%;
    overflow: auto;
}
div nav{
    overflow: auto;
    float:right;
    width:285px;

}
#content {
/* Height of the footer element */
    padding-bottom:120px;

}


}
#footer {
    /*yellow footer*/
      position:fixed;
      background: #f9e933;
      min-width:855px;
      bottom: 0;
      height:120px;
 }
 #contact{
     float:left;
     width:570px;
     background: #f9e933;
     height:120px;
     padding
 }
 #sitemap {
     float:right;
     width:285px;
     background: #f9e933;
     height:120px;
  }

  #left{
    margin: 20px;
    float:left;
    width:570;
    overflow: auto;
  }

   #right{
      float:right;
      width:285;
      overflow:auto;
   }
   .container {
      max-width:855;
      margin: auto;
      column-count: 2;
  }
    #wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width:855px;

  }
```

Comment: Why does your reset come after your style? And where is your CSS code?

Comment: i didnt think it mattered

Comment: post your css code

Comment: *"i didnt think it mattered"* - Order of CSS definitely matters.